# Using an array declared in one function to another function

Tags: c++, function

I am currently stuck on a part of programming. 
I've made a function to get the amount of rows and columns for a 2D array and then filled that array up with information from an input file.

I now need to use that array in another function to display the array.
Here is the current code. 
Furthermore I cannot modify the function definitions in any way so I'm pretty sure I have to use pointers and those really confuse me.

Could someone clarify or help?

```
void populateWorld (const char * file)
{

int numchar = 0;
int numline = 0;
char a;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("glider_gun_fight.txt");
inFile.get(a);
while(inFile)
{
    while(inFile && a != '\n')
    {
        numchar = numchar + 1;
        inFile.get(a);
    }
    numline = numline + 1;
    inFile.get(a);
}
ROWS = numline;
COLUMNS = numchar / numline;
inFile.close();

inFile.open("glider_gun_fight.txt");


char gameBoard[ROWS][COLUMNS];
for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++)
    {
        inFile >> gameBoard [r][c];
    }
}
inFile.close();
}

//This function outputs the grid for current generation (add high level 
//description of your implementation logic) 
void showWorld ()
{
for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++)
    {
        cout << gameBoard [r][c];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `string` with `getline` instead of getting and counting character by character? Also if you are not allowed to change the function declaration, then you need to use a global variable for the board, which might not be what you want to do (certainly it is not a nice solution)

Comment: My instructor has restricted us from use of string because it would be "too easy" to which I rolled my eyes but oh well. 
Also I do not know the size of the input file because it is arbitrary so it could be any sort of size which is why I have that first starting bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the function declaration, the only possibility left is a global variable:

```
char **gameBoard;

void populateWorld (const char * file) {
    //...
    //char gameBoard[ROWS][COLUMNS]; //Not local anymore, instead allocate dynamically:
    gameBoard = new char*[ROWS];
    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        gameBoard[r] = new char[COLUMNS];
        for(int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++)
        {
            inFile >> gameBoard [r][c];
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Then the other function works as it is. However one should avoid global variables. (Although `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` seem to be global already, so one more doesn't do much harm.)

Don't forget to release the allocated memory again with `delete[]` when it isn't needed anymore.

And as I said there are other methods in C++, like `string`, `getline` and `vector`, which one really should use instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand it now. With pointers the memory isn't cleared after the function is done running so I can use it in the next function. 

And yeah the instructor said I couldn't use string, getline, or vector and pretty much limited us in a variety of ways so I had to do this to get the program to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the function declaration you are unable to pass the array created in this function in outer world.:)
Also take into account that your function is not C++ compliant. In C++ sizes of arrays ahall be constant expressions at compilation time. 
Moover if the file contains tab characters then its ouput can be something differenrt than you expected.